# Split records based on timeline in 2 tables in SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have 2 tables, Say - Customer and Car with timeline for each record.

I have to consider Customer as a Driving table and Car as a lookup table and show all records from Customer table and matching from the Car table but with proper timeline.

If you look at the expected output, we need to join and split the records in such a way that -

- If, for any time period a customer is not having any Car associated then that will be one record (Example - John with Delhi City from 01-Jan-14 to 01-Feb-14, 01-Jul-14 to 01-Oct-14 and 01-Nov-14 to 01-Jan-15)
- If, Customer is having any car associated for a time period then that will be another record (Example - John with Delhi City from 01-Feb-14 to 01-Jul-14 and 01-Oct-14 to 01-Nov-14)

**Customer**

| ID | City | Effective DT | Expire DT |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| John | Mumbai | 1-Jan-12 | 31-Mar-12 |
| John | Delhi | 31-Mar-12 | 31-Dec-12 |
| John | Chennai | 31-Dec-12 | 1-Jul-13 |
| John | Pune | 1-Jul-13 | 31-Dec-13 |
| John | Delhi | 1-Jan-14 | 1-Jan-15 |

**Car**

| Customer_ID | Car | Effective DT | Expire DT |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| John | Tesla | 10-Apr-12 | 10-May-12 |
| John | Hyundai | 31-Dec-12 | 1-May-13 |
| John | Honda | 1-Oct-13 | 31-Dec-13 |
| John | KIA | 1-Mar-13 | 1-Oct-13 |
| John | Ford | 1-Feb-14 | 1-Jul-14 |
| John | Suzuki | 1-Oct-14 | 1-Nov-14 |

**Expected Output**

| ID | City | Car | Effective DT | Expire DT |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| John | Mumbai |  | 1-Jan-12 | 31-Mar-12 |
| John | Delhi |  | 31-Mar-12 | 10-Apr-12 |
| John | Delhi | Tesla | 10-Apr-12 | 10-May-12 |
| John | Delhi |  | 10-May-12 | 31-Dec-12 |
| John | Delhi | Hyundai | 31-Dec-12 | 31-Dec-12 |
| John | Chennai | Hyundai | 31-Dec-12 | 1-May-13 |
| John | Chennai | KIA | 1-Mar-13 | 1-Jul-13 |
| John | Pune | Honda | 1-Oct-13 | 31-Dec-13 |
| John | Pune | KIA | 1-Jul-13 | 1-Oct-13 |
| John | Delhi |  | 1-Jan-14 | 1-Feb-14 |
| John | Delhi | Ford | 1-Feb-14 | 1-Jul-14 |
| John | Delhi |  | 1-Jul-14 | 1-Oct-14 |
| John | Delhi | Suzuki | 1-Oct-14 | 1-Nov-14 |
| John | Delhi |  | 1-Nov-14 | 1-Jan-15 |

I have tried using left join with filters on checking Car table Effective or Expire Time should always be between Effective and Expire Time of Customer Table effective and Expire Time and able to get the partial result but facing challenges to get the records where Car is partially tagged to a customer *( Like records with John -> Delhi -> Empty Car information in the expected output table)*